# How to find out Org ID if locked out of Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce-id, org

How do I find out our Org ID if we're locked out of Salesforce?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to... you'd need to contact support.

Comment: If you are a system admin, a good lead would be to search through your email box for an email containing “developer script exception”